# how to require images that are passed in as prop names into react component?

Tags: image, reactjs, webpack

Lets say I have a bunch of local images that are part of my react project. I have a component that accepts props from higher up -- and one of the props is image name.  So using , this could work.  The tricky part is that I am using webpack, and I think thats why my images dont get displayed -- they arent pulled in. 
So before I had converted my component to use props, the image name was hardcoded, and worked like this:

```
        <img src={require('../images/products/image-aqua.png')}/>
```

but now it looks as following, and doesnt work:

```
    <img src={this.props.productImageUrl} />
```

Essentially, I am trying to stradle react "on the fly" image names and webpack packing concepts (I do know about webpack url-loader and file-loader)
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should probably post your webpack so we can help you further. Your code above should work no problem.

Here is my webpack for img and such and it works as you are trying to use it.

```
{
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|tiff|svg)$/,
        exclude: /\.glyph.svg/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 6000,
              name: 'image/[name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

The only other issue you could be encountering is that your images aren't actually loaded when your component loads. Are you getting any errors or they just aren't showing?

[image]

```
class ProductList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const product = Seed.products[0];
        return (
            <div className='ui unstackable items'>
                <Product
                    id={product.id}
                    title={product.title}
                    description={product.description}
                    url={product.url}
                    votes={product.votes}
                    submitterAvatarUrl={`${product.submitterAvatarUrl}`}
                    productImageUrl={`${product.productImageUrl}`}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Product extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log("image name " + `${this.props.productImageUrl}`);

        return (
            <div className='item'>
                <div className='image'>
                    <img src={`${this.props.productImageUrl}`} /> {/*this.props.productImageUrl*/}
                </div>
                <div className='middle aligned content'>
                    <div className='header'>
                        <a>
                            <i className='large caret up icon' />
                        </a>
                        {this.props.votes}
                    </div>
                    <div className='description'>
                        <a href={this.props.url}>
                            {this.props.title}
                        </a>
                        <p>
                            {this.props.description}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className='extra'>
                        <span>Submitted by:</span>
                        <img
                            className='ui avatar image'
                            src={`${this.props.submitterAvatarUrl}`}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <ProductList />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

...

```
import aqua from '../images/products/image-aqua.png';
import daniel from '../images/avatars/daniel.jpg';


export default window.Seed = (function () {
  function generateVoteCount() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 15);
  }

  const products = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Yellow Pail',
      description: 'On-demand sand castle construction expertise.',
      url: '#',
      votes: generateVoteCount(),
      submitterAvatarUrl: daniel,
      productImageUrl: aqua,
    },
```

Comment: Images just arent showing -- I am getting empty rectangles where they are supposed to be.  I am trying to figure out if I have a wrong path somewhere

Comment: Have you console.log'ed exactly where you are using this.props.productImageUrl? (like one line above) And you are for sure it's not an async issue where the component is rendering first before the image data is ready?

Comment: the problem is that I am a newbie and dont know what I am doing :).   I am working on simple sample project -- no async anything there.  Its a pure lack of "how to" -- like specifying the wrong path or something equivalent

Comment: do you have it on github where I could look at it further maybe and help?

Comment: wow, ok, lets try it.  Here it is: https://github.com/alernerdev/fullstack-react        there are 2 files of interest under src -- app.js and productSeed.  Thats it.  The seed file contains an array of "products" and the app tries to display the first product -- not even all of them.  Just one.  But I want to do it through props.  THANK YOU

Comment: So with react and webpack you need to either IMPORT or REQUIRE the image somewhere.... When you stopped require'ing the image it broke because webpack. Within the scope of your project you need to import each image as a name, in the seed.js. Check the updates!

Comment: thank you for going the extra mile, thank you, happy new year

Comment: Look at my original answer, I posted a picture and two code snippets that should fix your code.